# Angular Material Table with Firebase Is Empty When MatTableDataSource Used

Tags: angular, firebase, datatable, firebase-authentication, angular-material

When I use MatTableDataSource for my table for data from Firebase the table is empty. When I save the data from Firebase to a variable the table works fine, I have no idea what is going on but I would like to use MatTableDataSource for the ease of use for sorting so if anyone could point out where I'm going wrong it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

html snippet:

```
//This will have a populated table
//<mat-table #table [dataSource]="itemList">

//This will have an empty table
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

...
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

</mat-table>
```

ts snippet:

```
itemList: Item[];
...
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.itemList);

// Connect to firebase db with Item Service
constructor(private itemService: ItemService) { }

ngOnInit() {

    let data = this.itemService.getData();
    data.snapshotChanges().subscribe(item => {
        this.itemList = [];
        item.forEach(element => {
            let json = element.payload.toJSON();
            json["$key"] = element.key;
            this.itemList.push(json as Item);
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: populate the datatable inside subscribe

Comment: Thanks so much that was it! If you add that as a answer I'll be sure to accept it.

Comment: glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working with [async programming](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript)  your subscription will be resolved later and you were trying to initialize the data-table with the data which has not been delivered yet. you need to populate the datatable inside `subscribe` callback to ensure that it is only initialized when your subscription is resolved Refer [this](https://developer.telerik.com/topics/web-development/introduction-observables-angular-developers/) for better understanding.

```
// Connect to firebase db with Item Service
constructor(private itemService: ItemService) { }
 dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(Item[]);

ngOnInit() {

    let data = this.itemService.getData();
    data.snapshotChanges().subscribe(item => {
        this.itemList = [];
        item.forEach(element => {
            let json = element.payload.toJSON();
            json["$key"] = element.key;
            this.itemList.push(json as Item);
           this.datasource= new MatTableDataSource(this.itemList)
           //this.datasource.data=this.itemList;

        });
    });

}
```